# Performance difference between arrays, stacks and queues

Tags: java, arrays, stack, queue

What is the search performance of arrays, stacks and queues?

I think that arrays are the quickest and most straightforward, because I can access any element immediately by calling it using its index. Is this correct?  What about the performance of stacks and queues?  How do they compare?

Comment: Your question is quite broad, could you be more specific about what you are asking?

Comment: My teacher asked me to compare between the arrays from one side , and the stacks and queues from the other. The comparison should tackle three of the following:

Arrays  vs.  stacks and queues:

a-their roles
b- access restrictions
c- ease of search
d- insert or delete operations.

Comment: In Java there is an array implementation for all the collections you mention.  For a brute force search the performance should be basically the same.  You could make assumptions that some operations are more expensive than others, however they all have the same O(N) to search N elements, so any conclusions you come to about differences based on theory is unlikely to be useful IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how your search (or which search algorithm) is implemented. `Stack` or `Queue` may also helpful for some searching application like - `BFS`, `DFS`. But in normal case when you are using linear search you can consider about array or `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer in a very simple way.

Stacks and queues are for storing data temporarily so that you can process the contents one by one. Just like a queue for buying movie tickets, or a stack of pancakes, you process one element at a time.

Arrays are for storing data as well as for accessing elements from the beginning, the end or in between. For searching, arrays would be a better choice.

Can you search elements inside stacks and queues? Possibly. But that's not what they are used for.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays (and collections based on arrays, eg. `ArrayList`) are bad for search performance because in the worst case you end up comparing every item (`O(n)`).
But if you don't mind modifying the order of your elements, you could sort the array (`Arrays.sort(yourArray)`) then use `Arrays.binarySearch(yourArray, element)` on it, which provides a `O(log n)` performance profile (much better that `O(n)`).

Stacks are in `O(n)`, so nope.

Queues are not even meant to be iterated on, so looking for an object in here would mean consuming the whole queue, which is 1. not performant (`O(n)`) and 2. probably not what you want.

So among the datastructures you suggested, I would go for a sorted array.

Now, if you don't mind considering other datastructures, you really should take a look at those who use hash functions (`HashSet`, `HashMap`...).
Hash functions are really good at searching for elements, with a performance profile in `O(1)` (with a good `hashcode()` method in your objects).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers ,, 
I still don't know how to write my answer .. This is a homework from my teacher .
I did not understand some answers because I am still a beginner in Java :)

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do your homework for you. We can answer questions but you need to prove you understand.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you have `ArrayList` (built on an array), a `Stack` (built on an array) and an `ArrayQueue` and ArrayDeque (which is also built on an array)  As they all use the same underlying data structure their access speeds are basically the same.

For a brute force search, the time to scan or iterate over them (all of them support iteration) is O(n) Btw even a HashMap uses an array to store it's entries which is why iterating over its elements to find a value e.g. `containsValue` is O(n) as well.

While you could have a sorted array which would more naturally sit in an ArrayList, you could equally argue that a PriorityQueue will find and remove the next element the most efficiently. A Stack is ideal for finding the most recently added element.

To answer the question you have to determine what assumption the person asking the question is making.  Without these further assumption you would have to say they could all be utilised.  In that case I would use an ArrayList as it is the simplest to understand IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

stack, queue and array all are three different and efficient data structures but as a bioinformatician if you want to store biological data, you should choose stack as data structure because last in and first out characteristic of recursive procedure shows that it is the most suitable data structure. Recursion is actually a characteristic of stack. At each procedure call a value can easily be pushed in it and can be retrieved when you exit from procedure. So it actually an aesy to use method.

Answer (score 0):

See you can not compare one data structures with another. Each one has their own advantage and disadvantage.

Although array are good but you can not use them all the time because of their fixed size. They are use for inserting, deleting etc because they need O(1) time.

But when you want to access and insert data from one way only and don't want to perform searching, deleting in between you go for stack and queue. Stack and queue differ only in method of accessing element. In stack you access data from same side you enter data[LIFO] requires O(1) time. In queue you access data from other corner [FIFO]. Accessing elements in between can be done, but that's not what they are used for.